# How to reference a set of checkboxes inside a table cell for any given row

Tags: javascript, reference, html-table

I have an HTML table with one cell per row that contains five checkboxes:

```
<td class="days">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="mon" id="mon" value="1" class="form-control" />M</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="tue" id="tue" value="2" class="form-control" />Tu</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="wed" id="wed" value="3" class="form-control" />W</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="thu" id="thu" value="4" class="form-control" />Th</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fri" id="fri" value="5" class="form-control" />F</label>
</td>
```

I need my javaScript to check the values of each checkbox to compare with something else. I have tried the following ways to get the value of the checkboxes mon, tue, wed, thu and fri but they don't seem to work:

```
var table = document.getElementById("leaveTable");
var monValue = table.rows[row].cells[5].namedItem("mon").firstChild.value;
```

(the cell containing the checkboxes has an index of 5)

I have multiple rows, all identical apart from the row index so that I can pass the row index as a parameter to my functions and the same functions will work irrespective of the row.

I'm only using javaScript and not JQuery, so please only answer with javaScript suggestions. Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/gt7hv3gs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) on the row to get all input elements in it

```js
var idx = 0;
var table = document.getElementById("leaveTable");
var inputs = table.rows[idx].querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'); //'input[type="checkbox"]:checked' if you want only checked
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  snippet.log(inputs[i].value + ':' + inputs[i].name + ':' + inputs[i].nextSibling.nodeValue)
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<table id="leaveTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="days">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mon" id="mon" value="1" class="form-control" />M</label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tue" id="tue" value="2" class="form-control" />Tu</label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="wed" id="wed" value="3" class="form-control" />W</label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="thu" id="thu" value="4" class="form-control" />Th</label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fri" id="fri" value="5" class="form-control" />F</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has allowed me to get the values of the checkboxes in the cell. However, it won't allow me to set the values. Is there a way to do this?